# Multiplicative group modulo $n$ is generated by large enough primes $p\equiv3\bmod4.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and consider the multiplicative group of units modulo $n$, i.e.,
$\big(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\big)^{\times} = \big\{ a : 1 \leq a \leq n-1  \text{ and } (a, n) = 1\big\}.$

I want to examine the following proposition:

For every $N$ consider the subgroup $G_{N}:=\langle\left\{ p\text{ prime} : p \equiv 3\hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } 4), p > N \right\}\rangle$ generated by large enough primes equivalent to 3 modulo 4. I want to show that $G_{N} = \big(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\big)^{\times}$ for some $N$.

I know that if $n = \prod_{i=1}^{k} p_{i}^{a_{i}}$, then $\big(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\big)^{\times} = \prod_{i=1}^{k} \big(\mathbb{Z}/p_{i}^{a_{i}}\mathbb{Z}\big)^{\times}$ but I cannot see why only primes $p$ equivalent to 3 modulo 4 suffice and finitely many of them can be disregarded.

Comment: From Dirichlet, given $\gcd(a,n)=1,$ there there inf8nitely many primes $p$ such that and $n$ is odd, there exists infinitely many  primes, $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod n$ and $p\equiv 3\pmod 4.$ The same is true if $n$ is divisible by $2$ but not $4.$ Seems like you can probably get the case when $n$ is divisible by $4$ with a little more work.